# Adding new entries to a ListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My goal is to be able to input two numbers into two separate `EditText fields`, do a quick calculation with the two numbers, and add the `three numbers + the date` to a list while keeping any old entries also so it will add another row to the table at the top.

```
 Date1  |  Num1  |  Num2  |  CalculatedNum3 

 Date2  |  Num4  |  Num5  |  CalculatedNum6
```

Above would be a rough layout of the design of the ListView.

I've looked into Arrays, Strings and Adapters but I can't seem to wrap my head around them; how I could use them in this situation. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are what you need:

1. A class contains those data: `Date1`, `Num1`, `Num2`, `CalculatedNum`
2. A custom adapter which extends from `BaseAdapter`
3. A layout for for an item within `ListView`
4. Main layout, which contain the `ListView`
5. Finally, the main activity which consists of two `TextView`, two `EditText` and one `Button`.

This is the most basic skeleton to set up a `ListView`, of-course you can implement all the view in code but try to follow this pattern. It will make your code cleaner and easier to adapt changes in layout.

**#1**

```
package com.example.demo;

public class Data {
    private int mX;
    private int mY;
    private int mSum;
    private String mDate;

    public Data(int x, int y, int sum, String date) {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mSum = sum;
        mDate = date;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return mX;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return mX;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return mSum;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }
}
```

**#2**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DemoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Data> mItems;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;

    private static LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public DemoAdapter(Context context, List<Data> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView x;
        TextView y;
        TextView sum;
        TextView date;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mHolder.x = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_x);
            mHolder.y = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_y);
            mHolder.sum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_sum);
            mHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        }
        else {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.x.setText(Integer.toString(mItems.get(position).getX()));
        mHolder.y.setText(Integer.toString(mItems.get(position).getY()));
        mHolder.sum.setText(Integer.toString(mItems.get(position).getSum()));
        mHolder.date.setText(mItems.get(position).getDate());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**#3**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="date">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="x">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="y">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="sum">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**#4**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Num 1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Num 2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**#5**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Data> mData;
    private ListView mListView;
    private DemoAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupListView();

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_x);
                EditText editY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_y);

                int x = Integer.parseInt(editX.getText().toString());
                int y = Integer.parseInt(editY.getText().toString());

                mData.add(new Data(x, y, x + y, "02/33/2033"));
                // add new data to list and refresh
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareDummyData() {
        mData = new ArrayList<Data>();
        mData.add(new Data(1, 2, 3, "07/22/2012"));
        mData.add(new Data(2, 3, 5, "07/23/2012"));
    }

    private void setupListView() {
        // add some data
        prepareDummyData();
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mAdapter = new DemoAdapter(this, mData);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need is a ListView.  A ListView is a view that orders its child views in a scrolling vertical list automatically depending on the elements present in the dataset observed by the Adapter given to it.  Essentially, there are three parts:

1. The dataset that contains the data you want to display.
2. The Adapter which provides an interface from that data to:
3. The view itself, which is responsible for displaying the data.

What you need to define is a mapping from some sort of collection to the Adapter so that the adapter knows how to access the data it needs to give to the ListView.  There are examples of this in the Android SDK and there's even a [ListView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Beyond that, there are two approaches to presenting your data in the ListView.  You can compute the string `"DateX | Num1 | Num2 | CalculatedNumX"` and simply have each list element be that string (simplest).  Or, you can create a custom view with 4 (or 7) text boxes and populate each one individually with the appropriate data.  This is more complex but has the advantage of providing more flexibility as to how you format and position your text.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, some better than others in certain situations.

**Understand the classes you will be using**

As posted in another answer you will need:

- A `ListView` of some flavour to display your data
- An adapter of some sort (`BaseAdapter` will do fine) to handle displaying your data
- A variable to store your data (I would recommend an `ArrayList`)
- A custom `Layout` to display each set of data in a row of your `ListView`

**Turning this into something working**

Firstly,its easiest just to make your components then link them last. So first up, your layout for each row of your `ListView`:

```
// Very basic layout for a row
public class rowView extends LinearLayout {
    TextView tv1 = null;
    TextView tv2 = null;
    TextView tv3 = null;
    TextView tv4 = null;

    public rowView(Context ct) {
        super(ct);

        // Do some Layout settings as needed
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // Create and configure TextViews
        tv1 = new TextView(ct);
        tv2 = new TextView(ct);
        tv3 = new TextView(ct);
        tv4 = new TextView(ct);

        tv1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tv2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tv3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
        tv4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

    // Add the views to the layout
        addView(tv1);
        addView(tv2);
        addView(tv3);
        addView(tv4);
    }
}
```

Next up is your data display, the way you link it to your `EditText`'s etc will vary. But here is some idea's on how you could use an `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Say when you calculate your third number, you call a function like below:

```
public void addData(String date, String num1, String num2, String calculatedNum) {
    String[] s = new String[4];

    s[0] = date;
    s[1] = num1;
    s[2] = num2;
    s[3] = calculatedNum;

    arrayListofStrings.add(s);
}
```

Now your data is stored. Last major step is simply creating your adapter which you have to to set up to correctly 'get your `ListView` to correctly talk with your data'. Seeing as your new data is added to the end of your `ArrayList` (which is a lot easier than trying to add it to the start), all you have to do is flip the order in your adapter like so:

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListofStrings.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // Returns the strings in REVERSE order
        return arrayListofStrings.get(arrayListofStrings.size() - 1 - position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // Not concerned with this
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Here is the version for memory optimization (aka view recycling). This should be habit

        rowView ret = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Create a new view
            ret = new rowView(getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            // Cast and reuse
            ret = (rowView) convertView;
        }

        // Get the data
        String[] data = (String[]) getItem(position);

        // Update the row with the data
        ret.tv1.setText(data[0]);
        ret.tv2.setText(data[1]);
        ret.tv3.setText(data[2]);
        ret.tv4.setText(data[3]);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

The last steps are just creating your `ListView` where you need it, creating and attaching your `Adapter` to your `ListView` and other minor things (like casting your values to Strings etc).

This is by no means a working solution, just the guts of what sort of thinking goes into it and what you will need to do.

**Note:** Whenever you change the data ensure you **call** [BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Just inflate a custom view on Override of  the getView method on the adapter being used by the ListView (instead of android_simple_listview_item). On your case supply layout_weight and weigh_sum attributes on the XML layout resource to control the apperance of your view. Just use the Date and Calendar java classes for the calculation of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own Custom Adapter. You will create your own layout, in which you can set any kind of an item which is created based on your own custom layout. Check out the following [link](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).It will definitely help you.

You can add your calculation once you are done with the basic ListView Adapters. For adding a layout at the top, One way of doing is to use a function called `adapt.insert(object, index)` where you basically provide an index of where to add an item. As an example, the link given above have a method called `getOrders()`.